# Deploy meteor project to galaxy from a bitbucket pipeline

Tags: meteor, bitbucket, meteor-galaxy

I am new in the Galaxy and I try to auto-deploy my application on each push to my BitBucket repository using the BitBucket Pipelines (this is a system that run shell commands after each push).

The problem is that I can't deploy in the Galaxy because the deploy command ask for my Galaxy credentials.

I know that it is possible to use a Token to avoid this problem but it is only available for 90 days.

Is there a way to write my credentials as a command parameter or an env variable ?

Here is the command I run via the pipeline:

`DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=\"eu-west-1.galaxy.meteor.com\" meteor deploy \"mydomain.com\" --settings ./settings.json --allow-superuser`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Galaxy token to login which is valid for 90 days.

https://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/commands.html#login-token

In summary, to retrieve the token, run:

`METEOR_SESSION_FILE=token.json meteor login`

To login with the token, use:

`METEOR_SESSION_FILE=token.json meteor deploy`

Comment: Not sure why the -1, this is the official method.